# How to simply select specific number of specific rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, rows

Followings are my data,

```
num<- c(6,8,7,5,9,6,7)
x<- matrix(c(rep(1:7,num),rnorm(sum(num))), nrow=sum(num), ncol=2)
colnames(x)<-c("subject","value")
```

> x
>         subject       value
>    [1,]       1    0.35182560
>    [2,]       1  0.35933614
>   [3,]       1 -0.89029320
>    [4,]       1 -0.79991981
>   [5,]       1  1.10773640
>    [6,]       1 -1.73900484
>    [7,]       2  1.06632139
>    [8,]       2  0.71727759
>    [9,]       2  0.51002247
>   [10,]       2  1.36132224
>   [11,]       2 -0.85432175
>   [12,]       2 -0.49878742
>   [13,]       2  1.43705322
>   [14,]       2  0.34052593
>   [15,]       3 -0.43245360
>   [16,]       3  1.01687525
>   [17,]       3  0.48998138
>   [18,]       3 -1.06197379
>   [19,]       3 -0.19777785
>   [20,]       3  1.24940714
>   [21,]       3  0.47521229
>   [22,]       4 -0.99888249
>   [23,]       4 -0.12678874
>   [24,]       4 -1.14620801
>   [25,]       4 -1.29165060
>   [26,]       4  1.56110270
>   [27,]       5  0.82543156
>   [28,]       5 -0.61718617
>   [29,]       5  0.22357131
>   [30,]       5  0.59639380
>   [31,]       5  2.72122980
>   [32,]       5  0.58674354
>   [33,]       5  0.23674196
>   [34,]       5  0.78656422
>   [35,]       5  0.10426860
>   [36,]       6  0.93059568
>   [37,]       6  0.16065327
>   [38,]       6 -2.23496916
>   [39,]       6 -1.75680495
>   [40,]       6  0.49717967
>   [41,]       6  1.13033910
>   [42,]       7  0.71402667
>   [43,]       7 -0.06120018
>   [44,]       7 -0.67636605
>   [45,]       7  0.46402913
>   [46,]       7 -0.99090058
>   [47,]       7  1.58853435
>   [48,]       7 -1.15982415

My task is to select specific number of data in every subject to reform a new matrix. 
The specific number of each subject is

```
b<- ceiling(num*0.5)
```

which is

> b
>   [1] 3 4 4 3 5 3 4

That is to say, I need to extract 
first 3 rows of subject 1,
first 4 rows of subject 2,
first 4 rows of subject 3,
...
first 4 rows of subject 7,
to form a new matrix.

Following is my own coding:

```
b<- ceiling(a*0.5)
newx<- matrix(0, nrow=sum(b), ncol=2)
newx<- do.call(rbind, sapply(1:7, function(i){head(x[x[,1]==i,], b[i])} ) )
```

It works, but it takes time, is there any more simple way to work out this problem?

> newx
>         subject       value
>    [1,]       1  0.35182560
>    [2,]       1  0.35933614
>    [3,]       1 -0.89029320
>    [4,]       2  1.06632139
>    [5,]       2  0.71727759
>    [6,]       2  0.51002247
>    [7,]       2  1.36132224
>    [8,]       3 -0.43245360
>    [9,]       3  1.01687525
>   [10,]       3  0.48998138
>   [11,]       3 -1.06197379
>   [12,]       4 -0.99888249
>   [13,]       4 -0.12678874
>   [14,]       4 -1.14620801
>   [15,]       5  0.82543156
>   [16,]       5 -0.61718617
>   [17,]       5  0.22357131
>   [18,]       5  0.59639380
>   [19,]       5  2.72122980
>   [20,]       6  0.93059568
>   [21,]       6  0.16065327
>   [22,]       6 -2.23496916
>   [23,]       7  0.71402667
>   [24,]       7 -0.06120018
>   [25,]       7 -0.67636605
>   [26,]       7  0.46402913

Comment: What is 'a' in that calculation of b?

Comment: Sorry, "a" is the num<- c(6,8,7,5,9,6,7), i have modified it, thanks!

Comment: I thought so. I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R (assuming that `x` is ordered for the first column):

```
x[rep(match(unique(x[,1]),x[,1]),b)+sequence(b)-1,]
```

Comment: learned much from this concise and effective coding. Big Thanks!

Comment: I have tested 50,005,000 rows of data, this coding is the fastest!

Answer (score 3):

We `split` the sequence of rows in 'x' by the 'subject' column to create a `list`, use `Map` to get the `head` of each `list` element by specifying the `n` as 'b' (the corresponding elements of `list` and `vector` are used), `unlist` and subset the rows of the 'x'.

```
x[unlist(Map(head, split(seq_len(nrow(x)), x[,1]), b)),]
```

---

Another option is using `data.table`.  We convert the 'x' to 'data.table', create a second data.table with 'b', set the `key` column as 'subject', join both by `.EACHI` and get the `head` of `.SD`.

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- as.data.table(x)
d2 <- data.table(subject=seq_along(b), b)
setkey(d1, subject)
sekey(d2, subject)
d1[d2, head(.SD,b) , by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun, I gained the "Map" from your coding, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain 'half' the rows for each subject type, here is one way to do it with dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
num<- c(6,8,7,5,9,6,7)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(1:7,num),rnorm(sum(num))), nrow=sum(num), ncol=2))
df %>% group_by(subject) %>% slice(1:(n()/2))
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank u so much! but if the specific number is irregular, how can we do? For example, b<-c(2,1,3,1,2,3,1)

Comment: It is rounding down. Otherwise, you can explicitly use 'floor' or 'ceiling' around (n()/2) depending on what you want.